# ReactJS: Defining style attributes with functions

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

is it possible to define CSS inline styles by a function? I'm trying to do this:

```
render() {
var listStyle = {
    position: "relative",
    display: () => {
        console.log("Still alive")
        if(this.state.open) {
             return "block";
        }
        else return "none";
    }
return <li style={listStyle}>
.....
}
```

To no avail. It won't even log "Still alive", so the function doesn't even execute. I know there's no problem with assigning functions to objects in JS, so what gives?

Comment: It's expecting a string, not a function so it doesn't bother to execute your function. Sure JS allows you to do that, but that doesn't mean that react is expecting it or will handle it as you expect. Alternatively you could execute a function there that returns a string if you are so inclined.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the function (thankfully) wouldn't execute itself just because it exists. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to do like this, more simple

```
var listStyle = {
    position: "relative",
    display:this.state.open?'block':'none'
}
```

I think the style object just access the value in properties

but if you really like function. you can use self-executing anonymous function to make it run

```
var listStyle = {
    position: "relative",
    display: (()=>{
        console.log('alive')
        if(this.state.open){
           return 'block'
        }else{
           return 'none'
        }
    })()

}
```

Comment: I like your second example :) Thank you for sharing this

Comment: OK, so I forgot I could just () the function to have it execute. It wouldn't execute by itself just because I put "return" in there. Thanks!

Also yeah, the first alternative is more elegant for sure. For some reason it went totally out of my head to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with this

```
 const listStyle = {
   position: 'relative'
 }


const checkDisplay = open => {
  if (open) {
    return "block"
  }
  return "none";
}

<li style={{...listStyle, display: checkDisplay(this.state.open)}}></li>
```

Let me know if that work. Hope that can help you :)

Comment: It works! I'm going with the other answer because it's more elegant, but take this +1, you deserve it. ;)

Comment: Perfect, happy to hear that work :). And yes good choice for the other one I like it too ;)